# Backbone model level class method

Tags: backbone.js, model, class-method

I'm getting some model names dynamically and I want to access a method from each of the models. Is there a way that I can declare and access model level class method or constant in BB like Namespace.models["MyModel"].classMethod()/MY_CONSTANT?

Comment: You want all instances of `Backbone.Model` to have a specific method, or something else..?

Comment: I want a class method over model.

Comment: Sorry, I got my answer. I actually wanted a backbone model level static method.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how implement instance and class methods in Backbone.

```
var instance_properties = {
  myInstanceMethod: function() {console.log('instance method');}
};

var class_properties = {
  myClassMethod: function() {console.log('class method');}
};
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend(instance_properties ,class_properties);

Model.myClassMethod(); // class method

var model = new Model();

model.myInstanceMethod(); // instance method
```

Comment: Appreciate the example, I think that should be:  
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend(instance_properties ,class_properties);